# Filtering in Django by a set of String

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to find in django, all the elements in a table that start with one string in a set of strings. I know that we can filter with *__startswith* to find the elements that start with a string, and also, we can filter with *__in* to find into a set of numbers. How I can merge them?

For example, for this model

```
class Inventary:
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Suppose that I have the three elements:

1. 1.01.2 ---- Object1
2. 1.02.3 ---- Object2
3. 1.03.4 ---- Object3

Thus, I want a filter that allow me find the Objects that start with some string in the list L at the same time, where L in this case is ["1.01","1.02"].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q

>>> values = ['1.01', '1.02']

>>> query = Q()
>>> for value in values:
...     query |= Q(name__startswith=value)

>>> Inventary.objects.filter(query)
```

It dynamically builds a query that'll fetch the objects whose `name` starts with `1.01` or `1.02`:

```
>>> Inventary.objects.filter(Q(name__startswith='1.01') | Q(name__startswith='1.02'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple filters like this:

```
model.objects.filter(name__startswith='1.01').filter(name__startswith='1.02')
```

Comment: Hello hsfzxjy, thank for your answer, but I want to do this dinamically.  For example, to filter  the strings into a list ["1.01","1.02"] that can change.

Comment: Unfortunately, theres no such a functionality in SQL, nor does django ORM. You might achieve this by using a loop to chain the filter conditions together.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q

>>> values = ['1.01', '1.02']

>>> objects = Inventary.objects
>>> for value in values:
...     objects = objects. filter(name__startswith=value)

>>> objects
```